# Moving Wordpress to another domain with different permalinks

Tags: redirects

I want to move Wordpress to another domain and also change the permalinks. So basically what I want is to move from: oldsite.com/PostId-PostName.html to newsite.com/PostName/

I know this can be done from .htaccess, but I don't manage to get it right. Can you please help me ?

Comment: What is your url structure and what will the new be?

Comment: Cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452882/moving-wordpress-to-another-domain-with-different-permalinks

Comment: I'm going to close this one since the one at StackOverflow already has good answers and we have none here.